# Spring MVC with boot and NEO4j

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I am building an application where Rest endpoints uses, boot bindings to send Neo4j Entitites to Neo4j Repo, and thats the pattern we repeated few times across jpa backed repositories. In current configuration;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

JPA repositories and neo4j repositories works ok, until i add;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Erros i am facing are;

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

```
Constructor in org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.Neo4jOgmEntityInstantiatorConfigurationBean required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- mvcConversionService: defined by method 'mvcConversionService' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]
- integrationConversionService: defined in null
```

:: Spring Boot ::             (v2.1.0.M2)
   :: Java 8

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, but knows that this problem existed. It was solved in (at least) spring-data-neo4j 5.2.1 which is the default version in a Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE application. Any reasons why you are using the M2 and not the release version of Spring Boot?

Comment: since you are using spring boot try adding springboot starter neo4j instead of spring starter neo4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating project dependencies to

```
    <spring.boot.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.cloud.version>2.1.0.RC3</spring.cloud.version>
```

has fixed the issue as per @meistermeier suggestion.